Is seekg used to offset the input position by zero? If so, why would you do that?
I found the following code at this StackOverflow answer. It reads a file containing floats as binary:
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

// ...

// Open the stream
std::ifstream is("input.dat");
// Determine the file length
is.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
std::size_t size=is.tellg();
is.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);
// Create a vector to store the data
std::vector<float> v(size/sizeof(float));
// Load the data
is.read((char*) &v[0], size);
// Close the file
is.close();

What I am a little uncertain of is the line:
is.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);

which is supposed to offset the input position from 0 by std::ios_base::beg if I have understood it correctly. But isn't std::ios_base::beg always 0 since it refers to the beginning of the stream? Meaning is.seekg(0) or is.seekg(std::ios_base::beg) would have achieved the same but simpler.

Probably just to make the contrast with the seek(..., end) call, which set the file position at the end.

Refer to the documentation for seekg for specifics, but there are essentially two function signatures here.
    istream& seekg (streampos pos);

This sets an absolute position, 0-indexed from the beginning of the file.
    istream& seekg (streamoff off, ios_base::seekdir way);

This other sets a position relative to one of three options: (1) the beginning, (2) the current position, or (3) the end, of the stream.
So, is.seekg(0) and is.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg) are equivalent. Your example may work if it compiles, but only through the dumb luck that std::ios_base::beg has a value of 0. I would argue that this should be considered a bug, especially for some system that uses different values for these constants.
The former may be simpler, but the latter is clearer. And always remember to be nice to the poor sucker that has to maintain your code because it will probably be you.
